# Oracle 10g: Logoff trigger is not firing

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I am working on Oracle 10.2.0.4.0. It is a RAC setup with 2 nodes.
I have created a LOGON and LOGOFF trigger to identify a particular user and to do some cleanup work.

The LOGON trigger capturing the user session appropriately but the LOGOFF trigger does not fire at all when the user disconnects.

Code is something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER XXX.LOGOFF_TRIG_XXX
   BEFORE LOGOFF
   ON DATABASE
BEGIN
  IF     UPPER (SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'SESSION_USER')) = 'XXX'
     AND UPPER (SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'MODULE')) LIKE 'YYY%'
..
END;
/
```

This trigger works fine on a cloned environment properly.
Can anyone suggest what could be the issue and how to resolve it?  Thanks

Comment: How are you concluding that the trigger is not firing. Can you log to a table just before the IF statement in your trigger to be very certain that the trigger is not firing. Looking at the code snippet it might happen that the trigger is firing but the IF condition is not getting satisfied.

Comment: The trigger has code to insert into a row into a log table when user disconnects. Since there is no such entry for LOGOFF trigger , I came to the conclusion that it is not triggering at all.

As you said I tried placing the INSERT at the top and checked but still the trigger is not firing.

And also, I have tested these 2 triggers on a clone environment where they are working fine everyday.

Comment: I suspect this issue is either because of RAC setup or connection pooling. But I don't know how to verify that. Can anyone please guide??